# QGIS: Lengths of Clipped Road Network not adding up correctly

Tags: qgis, clip

I have a road network totaling length of 25,603 km. I clipped the entire network into 7 layers using 7 geographic divisions as boundaries. When I calculate the total length of the clipped roads from the 7 layers and add them, the total length I get is 25466 km, which is much less than the original length (25,603km).

There is not gap between the 7 geographic divisions; they are all adjacent to each other. Can anyone help understand why this discrepancy in the total length after clipping? and whats the solution to this?

Comment: could you check if there are duplicates in you original file?
Could you tell us which algorithm you are using to compute the lengths of the roads?

Comment: Hi sorry, saw your comment only today. The issue is solved; actually there were roads lying outside the 7 polygons representing geographic divisions so the total was not adding up. I discovered that using the topology checker tool. Thanks for the reply anyway.